# What would the loop look like to modify an array like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Is there a way in javascript to iterate through every value of a specific key from an object that is part of an array of objects and then create a new item for each value using a different key? Please allow me to explain with code what I would like to accomplish here.

This is what I have:

```
const x = [{
  name: 'name1',
  value: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  value: ['value4', 'value5', 'value6']
}]
```

This should be the new result:

```
const y = [{
  'name1': 'value1',
  'name2': 'value4',
}, {
  'name1': 'value2',
  'name2': 'value5',
}, {
  'name1': 'value3',
  'name2': 'value6',
}]
```

Any help will be truly appreciated!

Here is what I've tried so far. (It works, but I'm pretty sure there is a simpler way).

```
const y = [];
const z = [];
const xLength = x.length

for (let i = 0; i < xLength; i++) {
  x[i].value.forEach((item, index) => {
    z[index] = z[index] || [];
    z[index].push(x[i].name, item);
  });
}
z.forEach((items, index) => {
  const obj = {};

  items.forEach((item, k) => {
    if (k % 2) {
      obj[items[k - 1]] = item;
    } else {
      obj[item] = null;
    }
  });

  y.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: Use nested loops that create the new object and push it onto the result array.

Comment: The outer loop iterates over the indexes of the `value` arrays. The inner loop iterates over the `x` array, getting the `name` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```js
//start with array to store the answer
let y = []

//Next iterate threw each object in your 'x' array passing in to the callback xObj which is each object in your x array
x.forEach((xObj)=> {
  //store the name value just to make it easier to read
  let name = xObj.name

  //iterate through the values in each xObj, getting the 'value' and the index
  xObj.value.forEach((value, index)=>{
    
    //check if the y array has anything at the same index, if not create a blank object
    if(!y[index]) y[index]= {}

    //put in that object a key:value with the 'name' and 'value'
    y[index][name] = value 
    })
})
```